# Issues instaling MIME::Lite via CPAN on Mac OS X

Tags: perl, macos, osx-leopard, cpan

I am trying to install MIME::Lite using CPAN via Mac OS X Leopard and CPAN just keeps reporting back the following message:

```
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9304)  
ReadLine support enabled

cpan[1]> install MIME-Lite  
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.21)
Going to read /private/var/root/Library/Application Support/.cpan/Metadata  
    Database was generated on Mon, 09 Nov 2009 03:28:37 GMT  
Warning: Cannot install MIME-Lite, don't know what it is.  
Try the command  

    i /MIME-Lite/  

to find objects with matching identifiers.  
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.86)  

cpan[2]> i /MIME-Lite/  
Distribution    ALIAN/MIME-Lite-HTML-1.23.tar.gz  
Distribution    CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04.tar.gz  
Distribution    HORIUCHI/MIME-Lite-TT-0.02.tar.gz  
Distribution    HORIUCHI/MIME-Lite-TT-Japanese-0.08.tar.gz  
Distribution    RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.027.tar.gz  
Distribution    TYPESTER/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-Japanese-0.05.tar.gz  
6 items found
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `install MIME::Lite`. It should search by package name instead of file name.

Answer (score 1):

At the command line, just tell `cpan` which *module* to install:

```
 cpan MIME::Lite
```

You were giving it part of a distribution name.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is more than one distribution matching `"MIME-Lite"`. You can install the specific distribution you want by referring to it by name (e.g. `install RJBS/MIME-Lite`), but just `install MIME::Lite` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open terminal

2) Type sudo CPAN

3) Type install Module::name
e.g, install MIME::Lite

It will install MIME::Lite module for you.